# Casting generic type variable to guid, int, double, etc

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, guid, generic-programming

I read some strings from an XML file. Now I walk through my generic object (T) properties (new T().PropertyInfo), read the type and want to cast the xml-string to these properties.

When I use a `Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType)` it crashes on changing a string to a Guid. Sometimes I have Guid's, sometimes int32, sometimes bool, sometimes string, etc.

Has anyone an idea of how to convert a string to ANY type that is possible?

Oh... and btw. I only have property.PropertyType (a Type VARIABLE), I don't have a T here.

Comment: use `new Guid("your_guid_string")` to convert strings to a GUID. Unfortunately it's not possible using Convert.ChangeType...

Comment: But then I would have to know that the string contains a guid... isn't there a generic method out there to help me here?

Comment: I'd use something like `public static T Convert<T>(this String value) where T : struct =>(T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);`

Comment: I dont know if that works, but I have no T, only a type variable. I wouldnt know how to use that as T equivalent.

Comment: Is there a generic method to handle conversion from string to any type? No, there is not.  Consider the string "123", is that a string, int number, or decimal?  That depends on your business logic to determine what it is.  I would suggest you create a method that interrogates `PropertyType` and calls the appropriate converter.  This method will be *your* generic converter for the current use case.

Comment: What is the value for `PropertyType`?

Comment: Sometimes Guid (System.Guid), sometimes int32 (System.Integer), and so on... I will try it now with a case by case converter. Only negative about that is, when I get a type I didn't used by now, I will get an exception and have to change the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the guid as string.

Otherwise I think a series of TryParses with ChangeType being the option if everything else fails could work for strings.